# How to move an endpoint of a polyline feature to specific coordinates

Tags: arcobjects, c#

What looked like a simple task has kept me busy for a while now. I would like to snap the endpoint of a polyline feature to a known point of which I know the coordinates.

My first try was the following (within an edit operation):

```
polyline = feature.ShapeCopy as IPolyline;
polyline.ToPoint.PutCoords(_connectionPoint.X, _connectionPoint.Y);
feature.Shape = polyline;
feature.Store();
```

the new coordinates however would never be saved at the feature.

I also looked at this example:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_modify_a_specific_vertex_of_a_polyline/000100000023000000/

but I am a bit confused about whether I really need a HitTest in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just found a solution myself. I was already close. As stated above ToPoint.PutCoords doesn't work. But I could use this:

```
polyline = feature.ShapeCopy as IPolyline;
polyline.ToPoint = _connectionPoint
feature.Shape = polyline as IGeometry;
feature.Store();
```

maybe this is helpful for others looking for a simple way how to edit a polyline (end)vertex.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the specific point coordinates via [IPointCollection.Update](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/UpdatePoint_Method/002m0000028s000000/).